# PCB design all power connected together

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am new for PCB design. I don't want to steal your time with noob question but I don't know why this happened.

What I don't understand is, I am watching a video and he copies power and pastes it. (He is using same power VCC.) His power connection is separate. Each device goes to 5V separately. Here is a photo:

[image]

When I do the same thing, all my devices go to 5V together. Why do the devices' 5V pins converge? Is it a problem? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you going for a two layer design? If yes, you probably want to dedicate bottom side to ground plane with only short tracks you couldn't fit on the top layer there. Top layer for signal + routed 5V. Pour 5 V on top layer and connect once done.

Comment: There could be reason for isolating the supplies but that's not really the way to do it. These day you put a ferrite or even an inductor in series to clean out the noise. Or something similar to a 'star ground'. However these are too small tracks to begin with so these considerations seems to advanced

Comment: Thank you for comments. I thought 5V multiple line connection was a problem but now I got it. It is okay ,I will design this I don't need to connect ICs 5V each other I only need to connect to 5V. Separate or connected is don't matter.

Comment: As mentioned the question cannot really be answered without knowing if it's 2 layers or more. 5V layout will be very different on multi-layer boards where you might be able to give the supply a layer of its own. Which in turn likely gives much better EMC performance than routing traces around all over the place.

Comment: Okay thank you, I have new question. Now I am designing LM1117 3.3V regulator. It makes hole on PCB design.Will it be a problem ? or this hole works like place to cool off .

Answer (score 0):

The magic word is called Net.
Each net is a separate or independent potential. Everything that has the same net will connect together and everything with different nets will stay away from each other. The guy from the video probably gave each power a different net name or maybe those are not even power pins. The thin lines show which pins have the same net and will ultimately connect together. The guy from the video also has a pin like that, maybe that is VCC, I see 3 lines converging on it. The blue lines may be data lines.
You have to find out how to label or define the nets and then you have control over which pins come together and which don't.

Comment: Thank you for comment

Answer (score 0):

> When I do the same thing, all my devices go to 5V together. Why do the devices' 5V pins converge?

Because the PCB layout software doesn't know (or care) how the power is routed. It is just showing you that the power pins are connected.  It is up to you to route it.

Now *how* to route it is another story.  You could just do what the video does and it might be ok.

Otherwise, in real-world PCB design, you have to use your brain (a lot.)

- Should one or more components logically be at the *start* of the 5V supply?  Things like a reverse-protection diode, fuse, "on" indicator, 3.3V regulator, etc.
- Should certain components be at the *end* of the 5V tracks?  If all devices use 5mA each except one uses 0.5A, you wouldn't want to put the 0.5A device *last*.
  Because when it operates, it will cause the entire 5V trace to drop in voltage slightly, which could affect the other components.
- Should the GND and +5V tracks be wider than signal tracks?  Quite possibly. If the board uses 2A of power (as opposed to 15mA), then careful calculation of power track width is needed. This is to reduce losses (resistive heating) as well as preserve the 5.00V stability at the end of the track (so it is not 4.2V from track losses, which will cause major problems when this chip is supplied 4.2V but gets a digital input from elsewhere at 5.00V.)
- If all 5V devices are low-power (like 5mA each) and don't do anything unusual (like switch signals in the megahertz range, drive a motor, or regulate down to a lower voltage such as 3.3V) then it likely doesn't matter *how* or *in what order* they are supplied power.  So route the 5V tracks however is easiest.  It is common to begin layout, then find that the parts just don't connect well, so are rearranged, often several times.
- Anything which creates voltage transients (rapid changes in voltage/current such as a motor driver, switch-mode supply, power amplifier, many digital circuits including microcontrollers and line-drivers, etc.) *must* have appropriate bypass capacitors added to their supply rails, very close to the device.  This is to "bypass" the 5V supply (and use the reserve power from the capacitor) for the short periods where pulses happen.  This has the effect of mitigating voltage drop on the 5V traces, which stabilizes power and reduces EMI (electromagnetic interference.)
- Analog circuitry (op-amps, transistor amplifiers, ADC's, etc.) are especially sensitive to power transients and radiated emissions from nearby tracks. If greatly amplifying a small signal, you'll want to route those small (sensitive) signals far away from other (much larger) traces, or even protect them by running them alone above a ground plane.  *If a sensitive track must cross another track, do so perpendicularly - EMI will be greatest between two parallel tracks, and least between two perpendicular ones.*
- Lastly, be cognizant of *ground loops* with high-power switching devices.  This is the physical path current takes on the board when each device/load operates.  For 15mA boards, it likely isn't a concern.  But for the 2A board with switch-mode buck, microcontrollers, and motor driver, this *must* be carefully considered. For the same reason that delicate signals can be influenced by (small) perturbations on nearby tracks, high-power devices can create large perturbations on power input/output tracks, which can render the *entire board* inoperable.  Bypass capacitors are needed, but these alone are not enough - the placement of the components must be such that ground loops are minimized.

There are many posts here going into great detail about ground loops and the other topics, such as star grounding.

Comment: Thank you  @rdtsc I will try to abide by these articles

Comment: Generally in my experience , most designers today will opt for dedicated layers and planes  for powers and grounds and just drop vias and decoupling caps right at the IC . Board surface real estate is too expensive to dedicate to tracks!

Comment: While power planes are a convenient way to avoid running power traces, I purposely didn't mention them because they can make (visualizing) ground loops even more difficult.  Remediation may mean a split-ground plane and star-grounding, and/or a multi-layer board, which all add cost and complexity.  I suggest a newcomer start with easy designs first, and slowly progress to more challenging ones.

Comment: I don't quite agree, in my experience mediation is best handled through constraints at design phase through things like net ties , and through validated constraints on DRC, this puts more focus and emphasis on gathering requirements before starting layout. In my experience designers today are not prone to "eyeballing" quite so much anymore and design a process to manage complexity, this should be emphasized early on. IMO.

Comment: In either case it's actually pretty hard to screw up a ground plane, again, in my experience , of course there are always outliers ;) ;)